# Force wordfence to use custom blocked page

Tags: wordpress, wordfence

Is it possible to somehow edit wordfence, so I can use a custom / redirect visitors that are blocked somewhere?

The developers has been saying for years that it's "coming", but nothing happens..surely it must be possible to edit the code?

Comment: You shouldn't edit plugin code. So, if a user gets blocked (I'm assuming too many log in attempts or something), that it redirects that visitor to a specific page?

Comment: @disinfor yeah, I know, everybody says so, but I need that function, and it's available on other plugins, but they don't have wordfences security... All I need to know now is what file that's handling it